# Removing element from binary tree (2 children case)

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement a binary search tree, but I am stuck at element deletion. In particular, I think the two children case is wrong. Here is the current code:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

template<class T>
struct Node
{
    Node<T>* parent;
    Node<T>* left;
    Node<T>* right;
    T value;
};

template<class T, class Compare>
auto insertPosition(Node<T>* root, T value, Compare const& cmp)
{
    auto ret = root;
    auto current = root;
    auto res = false;
    while(current != nullptr)
    {
        res = cmp(value, current->value);
        ret = current;
        current = res? current->left : current->right;
    }
    return std::pair{ret, res};
}

template<class T>
auto& min(Node<T>& root)
{
    auto min_node = &root;
    while(min_node->left != nullptr)
    {
        min_node = min_node->left;
    }
    return *min_node;
}

template<class T>
auto& max(Node<T>& root)
{
    auto max_node = &root;
    while(max_node->right != nullptr)
    {
        max_node = max_node->right;
    }
    return *max_node;
}

template<class T, class Compare>
auto find(Node<T> const* root, T value, Compare const& cmp)
{
    auto ret = root;
    while(ret != nullptr)
    {
        auto const cmp_a = cmp(value, ret->value);
        auto const cmp_b = cmp(ret->value, value);
        if(!(cmp_a || cmp_b))
        { return ret; }

        if(cmp_a)
        { ret = ret->left; }
        else
        { ret = ret->right; }
    }
    return ret;
}

template<class T, class Allocator>
Node<T>* deleteNode(Node<T>* node, Allocator& alloc)
{
    if(node->left == nullptr && node->right == nullptr)
    {
        node->~Node<T>();
        alloc.deallocate(node, 1);
        return nullptr;
    }

    if(node->left == nullptr)
    {
        auto ret = node->right;
        node->~Node<T>();
        alloc.deallocate(node, 1);
        return ret;
    }

    if(node->right == nullptr)
    {
        auto ret = node->left;
        node->~Node<T>();
        alloc.deallocate(node, 1);
        return ret;
    }

    {
        auto& min_node = min(*node->right);
        min_node.left = node->left;
        min_node.parent = node->parent;
        node->~Node<T>();
        alloc.deallocate(node, 1);
        return &min_node;
    }
}

void dump(Node<int> const* root)
{
    if(root != nullptr)
    {
        if(root->left != nullptr)
        {
            printf("\"%d %p\" -> \"%d %p\"\n", root->value, root, root->left->value, root->left);
            dump(root->left);
        }
        if(root->right != nullptr)
        {
            printf("\"%d %p\" -> \"%d %p\"[arrowhead = diamond]\n", root->value, root, root->right->value, root->right);
            dump(root->right);
        }
    }
}

template<class T, class Allocator>
void deleteAll(Node<T>* root, Allocator& alloc)
{
    if(root != nullptr)
    {
        deleteAll(root->left, alloc);
        deleteAll(root->right, alloc);
        root->~Node<T>();
        alloc.deallocate(root, 1);
    }
}

template<class T, class Compare = std::less<T>, class Allocator = std::allocator<Node<T>>>
class BinaryTree:private Allocator, private Compare
{
public:
    BinaryTree():m_root{nullptr}{}

    explicit BinaryTree(Allocator&& alloc):Allocator{std::move(alloc)}, m_root{nullptr} {}

    ~BinaryTree()
    {
        deleteAll(m_root, static_cast<Allocator&>(*this));
    }

    void insert(T val)
    {
        auto node = new(Allocator::allocate(1))Node<T>{};
        node->value = val;
        auto [ins_pos, res] = insertPosition(m_root, val, static_cast<Compare const&>(*this));
        node->parent = ins_pos;

        if(ins_pos == nullptr) [[unlikely]]
        {
            node->left = nullptr;
            node->right = nullptr;
            m_root = node;
            return;
        }

        if(res)
        { ins_pos->left = node; }
        else
        { ins_pos->right = node; }
    }

    void erase_one(T val)
    {
        auto const node = const_cast<Node<T>*>(find(m_root, val, static_cast<Compare const&>(*this)));
        if(node == nullptr) [[unlikely]]
        { return; }

        auto parent = node->parent;

        if(parent == nullptr)
        {
            m_root = deleteNode(node, static_cast<Allocator&>(*this));
            return;
        }

        if(parent->left == node)
        {
            parent->left = deleteNode(node, static_cast<Allocator&>(*this));
            return;
        }

        parent->right = deleteNode(node, static_cast<Allocator&>(*this));
    }

    bool contains(T val) const
    { return find(m_root, val, static_cast<Compare const&>(*this)) != nullptr; }

    void dump()
    {
        ::dump(m_root);
    }

    T front() const
    {
        assert(m_root != nullptr);
        return min(*m_root).value;
    }

    T back() const
    {
        assert(m_root != nullptr);
        return max(*m_root).value;
    }

private:
    Node<T>* m_root;
};

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 23> vals{0,8,7,2,1,
8,  8,  4,  6,  1,
6,  6,  0,  4,  5,
0,  2,  3,  3,  4,
7,  8,  4};
    BinaryTree<int> test;
    std::ranges::for_each(vals, [&test](auto val){test.insert(val); });
//  test.dump();
//  fflush(stdout);

    std::ranges::for_each(vals, [&test](auto val){assert(test.contains(val)); });
    assert(test.front() == 0);
    assert(test.back() == 8);

//  test.erase_one(8);
}
```

It should be possible to store the same value multiple times, much like `std::multiset`. The reason for doing this is to see whether or not I can gain some speed to not bother about rebalancing, when I know that the input is not degenerate (that is, inserting already sorted data).

Comment: please add where you think it's wrong, better to have [mcve]

Comment: *"I think the two children case is wrong."* -- why do you think this? What did you observe that led you to this conclusion? Add enough code to your example so that we can copy and compile to code to also see this observation (or something equivalent). Then trim off all the code not necessary to reproduce your symptom. That is, make your *example* *reproducible* and *minimal*.

Comment: @JaMiT because it is the most complicated case.

Comment: @user877329 Every program has a most complicated case. Are you assuming that every program you write is wrong? That's rather cynical. You should entertain the idea that each program *might* be wrong, but reserve judgement until you've tested it. Stack Overflow requires a specific, known issue for questions seeking debugging help. Reviewing code is off-topic because it is extremely unlikely to help future visitors.